# Why use selectors and not a new URI?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, restful-url, clean-urls

I have a doubt, I have a URI that will bring me all user's account from another rest service. Example:

```
GET /users/21212/account
```

Now I have the need to bring 3 kinds of different groups of user's account, something like: "low-account", "medium-account" and "high-account".

But the discussion is, how should I enable this on my endpoint ?

```
GET /users/21212/accounts/low-account
GET /users/21212/accounts/medium-account
GET /users/21212/accounts/high-account
```

or

```
GET /users/21212/accounts/1?selector=low-account
GET /users/21212/accounts/1?selector=medium-account
GET /users/21212/accounts/1?selector=high-account
```

I'm inclinated to follow the first approach, I think is more intuitive and the manutenability of the code will be easily preserved... What do you think is conceptual right/better and why ?

Comment: Do these accounts mutually exclude each other?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the following option:

```
GET /users/12345/accounts?group=low-account
```

It will return you all accounts that belong to 'low-account' group for user 12345.

I tend to use query params if they represent something like filtering. Also I would recommend you to take a look at HATEOAS principle. Then you will be more flexible with your URIs.

Comment: This way I'll need to handle the parameters on my endpoint or any layer below with a group of ifs ? do you think this would be better than just call an uri and my endpoints calls my specific service methods?

Thanks for the answer, I'll check the HATEOAS principle !

Comment: Suppose you need to implement an endpoint to find accounts by an account type. Then you will come up with something like **GET /users/21212/accounts/accountTypeA**. The first drawback that I see it's a problem to easily combine operations "find accounts by group" and "find account by type". The second point is that for every new case you have to add one more endpoint. You might end up maintaining tons of such endpoints. However I do not know the domain and project details you have been working on. HATEOAS will help you to get a solution that is flexible enough and "refactorable".